# PHP handling XML Feed with Simple XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the UK Met office api to use some weather information. The XML is layed out as the following:

```
<SiteRep>
  <Wx>
    <Param name="F" units="C">Feels Like Temperature</Param>
    <Param name="G" units="mph">Wind Gust</Param>
    <Param name="H" units="%">Screen Relative Humidity</Param>
    <Param name="T" units="C">Temperature</Param>
    <Param name="V" units="">Visibility</Param>
    <Param name="D" units="compass">Wind Direction</Param>
    <Param name="S" units="mph">Wind Speed</Param>
    <Param name="U" units="">Max UV Index</Param>
    <Param name="W" units="">Weather Type</Param>
    <Param name="Pp" units="%">Precipitation Probability</Param>
  </Wx>
<DV dataDate="2013-08-28T08:00:00Z" type="Forecast">
<Location i="22" lat="53.5797" lon="-0.3472" name="HUMBERSIDE AIRPORT" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE">
  <Period type="Day" value="2013-08-28Z">
    <Rep D="SSW" F="19" G="9" H="59" Pp="0" S="4" T="20" V="VG" W="3" U="3">720</Rep> 
  </Period>
</Location>
<Location i="25" lat="53.8658" lon="-1.6606" name="LEEDS BRADFORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE">
  <Period type="Day" value="2013-08-28Z">
    <Rep D="SW" F="17" G="11" H="72" Pp="7" S="7" T="18" V="GO" W="7" U="3">720</Rep>
  </Period>
</Location>
</DV>
</SiteRep>
```

If I load this XML feed using simplexml_load_file and print_r I get the following output:

```
[Wx] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Param] => Array
            (
                [0] => Feels Like Temperature
                [1] => Wind Gust
                [2] => Screen Relative Humidity
                [3] => Temperature
                [4] => Visibility
                [5] => Wind Direction
                [6] => Wind Speed
                [7] => Max UV Index
                [8] => Weather Type
                [9] => Precipitation Probability
            )

    )

[DV] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [dataDate] => 2013-08-28T08:00:00Z
                [type] => Forecast
            )

        [Location] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [i] => 22
                                [lat] => 53.5797
                                [lon] => -0.3472
                                [name] => HUMBERSIDE AIRPORT
                                [country] => ENGLAND
                                [continent] => EUROPE
                            )

                        [Period] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => Day
                                        [value] => 2013-08-28Z
                                    )

                                [Rep] => 720
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [i] => 25
                                [lat] => 53.8658
                                [lon] => -1.6606
                                [name] => LEEDS BRADFORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT
                                [country] => ENGLAND
                                [continent] => EUROPE
                            )

                        [Period] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => Day
                                        [value] => 2013-08-28Z
                                    )

                                [Rep] => 720
                            )

                    )
```

My issue is the vital data I want are within Rep but I can't seem to handle it when using simplexml? should I do this another way or am i missing something?

Comment: Show us the code please. Also, what are you trying to extract from the above data?

Comment: You are missing `</SiteRep>` at the end.

Comment: I did not copy the whole XML feed as there are over 5000 locations, this was just a sample

Comment: Then remove 4998 of the locations so the XML remains valid. Unlike HTML, XML does not have a quirks mode to deal with invalid data.

Comment: Now Edited although solved anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one for getting `Rep`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

foreach($xml->DV->Location as $location)
{
    $att = $location->Period->Rep->attributes();

    echo $att['D'];
    echo $att['F'];
    echo $att['G'];
    echo $att['H'];

    etc...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I may not of been clear, its not the value of rep but the value of the attributes within the opening Rep tag.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting your XML I would suggest to use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) like this:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<EOF
<SiteRep>
    <Wx>
        <Param name="F" units="C">Feels Like Temperature</Param>
        <Param name="G" units="mph">Wind Gust</Param>
        <Param name="H" units="%">Screen Relative Humidity</Param>
        <Param name="T" units="C">Temperature</Param>
        <Param name="V" units="">Visibility</Param>
        <Param name="D" units="compass">Wind Direction</Param>
        <Param name="S" units="mph">Wind Speed</Param>
        <Param name="U" units="">Max UV Index</Param>
        <Param name="W" units="">Weather Type</Param>
        <Param name="Pp" units="%">Precipitation Probability</Param>
    </Wx>
    <DV dataDate="2013-08-28T08:00:00Z" type="Forecast">
        <Location i="22" lat="53.5797" lon="-0.3472" name="HUMBERSIDE AIRPORT" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE">
            <Period type="Day" value="2013-08-28Z">
                <Rep D="SSW" F="19" G="9" H="59" Pp="0" S="4" T="20" V="VG" W="3" U="3">720</Rep>
            </Period>
        </Location>
        <Location i="25" lat="53.8658" lon="-1.6606" name="LEEDS BRADFORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE">
            <Period type="Day" value="2013-08-28Z">
                <Rep D="SW" F="17" G="11" H="72" Pp="7" S="7" T="18" V="GO" W="7" U="3">720</Rep>
            </Period>
        </Location>
    </DV>
</SiteRep>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = '//SiteRep/DV/Location/Period/Rep';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    var_dump($entry->nodeValue);
}
```

If you need the attributes have a look at [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Comment: there is nothing for me to correct on the xml as it is supplied by the UK Met Office. If you were referring to the missing closing tags for DV WX and siterep it is because the whole XML feed is over 5000 locations. I just took a sample. I will look into DOMNode as it is the attributes of rep I am after. Thank You